# Databricks SQL skip rows

Tags: sql, csv, databricks, azure-databricks

I have 4 csv files and I would like to skip first 4 rows and start from 5th row as header while reading all of to make one table out of it.

Using this code

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ${personal.schema}.${personal.source}_test
USING CSV
OPTIONS (header "true", inferSchema "false", sep ",", multiLine "true", encoding 'UTF8',recursiveFileLookup  'true', skiprows '4' )
-- Change to right storage location
LOCATION 'abfss://......"
```

The problem is that one of the csv file has some input in the 4th row while rest of CSV are having 4th row as empty row. I notcited that all the headers are picked correctly in all csv 3 csv files and starting from the 5th row but for that one csv file it picks from 4th row.

How can I fix this?

I tried to create the seperte table only from the problematic csv file and mentioend `skip rows "5" and it gave me desired output.

without creating two saparte tables and then unioning them how can I avoid this problem?

Comment: Provide the csv you are using.

Answer (score 0):

The below approach will help you to achieve read CSV files in databricks and create one table out of it.

For example, I have 2 file 1 file have the rows starting from 4th and the second file from 5th row.

**Step 1:** You can read multiple CSV files using the below command

```
spark.read.csv("/FileStore/tables/*.csv",schema=schema).show()
```

**Output:**
[image]

**Step 2:** In the below code combining CSV files data and creating a SQL table

```
%sql
CREATE  TABLE  IF  NOT  EXISTS new_table02(id  Int, name varchar(50),age int, salary int)
USING CSV
OPTIONS (inferSchema "false", sep ",", multiLine "true")
LOCATION  "/FileStore/tables/*.csv"
```

**Step 3:** Ignore the NULL values from SQL table.

As you have mentioned, if you want a single table and not create two tables. You can use a select on the table created with a where Clause as shown below:

```
%sql
Select  *  from New_table02
where  id  is  not null
```

[image]